# How to randomly choose an item from an array with a 1000 items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Array example:

```
$scope.numbers=['AA','AB','AC'];
```

How to randomly chose an item from the array?

Comment: __It is not an array__

Comment: Get a random number between range and specify it as an `index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're actually using an array here is an example of how to do it:

[JSBin with the code below](https://jsbin.com/welati/1/edit?js,console)

```
var arr = ['AA', 'AB', 'BB'];

function rand() {
  // get a random index 
  var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[randIndex];
}

// run it ten times:
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(rand());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a random item from an Array, and not from an Object, you can use the code below

```
$scope.numbers=['AA','AB','AC'];

var len = $scope.numbers.length-1;
var random_index = Math.round(len * Math.random()));
var random_array_item = $scope.numbers[random_index]; // random array item assignment
```